# MYSQL Query troubles when no data provided

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a MYSQL table arranged like such: |ID|Year|Player|Stat|ETC|ETC|ETC|, and I've got a PHP form that queries perfectly, IF I enter both a year, and a player; however IF I'm missing one or the other it returns nothing. I've done some searching, but I can't seem to get this to work properly.  The relevant snippet is below:

```
//-query  the database table

if(!empty($year) && empty($name)) {$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Year = '$year'";
    }
    else if(!empty($name) && empty($year)) {$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Player = '$name'";
    }
    else if(!empty($year) && !empty($name)){$sql="SELECT * FROM Twins WHERE Year = '$year' AND Player = '$name'";
    }
    else if(empty($year) && empty($name)) {echo "Return to the previous page and enter data!";
    }
```

After this, I'm using a while loop to dump all the info to a table, I'm looking for anything overly complicated, I'd just like this to work... So, where have I screwed up?

index.php:

```
<form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform"> 
<select name="Years"> 
<option>"Pick A Year:"</option>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM database order by Year";
$r = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{ 
echo "<option>".$row['Year']."</option>\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
Player: <input type="text" name="Player">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Which dumps to search.php:

```
<table border="1"><tr><td>Year:</td>
<td>Year:</td> 
<td>Company:</td> 
<td>Set:</td> 
<td>Card Number:</td> 
<td>Have:</td>
</tr>
<?php 
//Player variable
$year=$_POST['Years'];
$name=$_POST['Player'];
//connect  to the database
include 'connect.php';
//-query  the database table
if(!empty($year) && empty($name)) {$sql="SELECT * FROM Twins WHERE Year = '$year' ORDER BY Company,Type,Year,Number";
}
else if(!empty($name) && empty($year)) {$sql="SELECT * FROM Twins WHERE Player = '$name' ORDER BY Company,Type,Year,Number";
}
else if(!empty($year) && !empty($name)){$sql="SELECT * FROM Twins WHERE Year = '$year' AND Player = '$name' ORDER BY Company,Type,Year,Number";
}
else if(empty($year) && empty($name)) {echo "Return to the previous page and enter data!";
}   
//-run  the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql);
//-create while loop and loop through result set
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$ID=$row['ID'];
$Year=$row['Year'];
$Company=$row['Company'];
$Card=$row['Number'];
$Type=$row['Type'];
$Have=$row['Have'];
echo "<tr>
<td>$Year</td>
<td>$Company</td>
<td>$Type</td>
<td>$Card</td>
<td>$Have</td>
</tr>";
} 
?> 
</table>
```

Comment: It seems fine. Can you show the variable initialization?

Comment: I assume the different table names in the FROM clause is just a typo?

Comment: Notice: Don't forget to sanitize your input. If you don't do this, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Comment: Edited in both files. 

Looking into sanitizing after I've got it up running. 

Have three options where year empty, where player is empty, or where both are empty.

Comment: ***WARNING: SQL Injection risk right ahead!!!*** [Please read here](http://bobby-tables.com)